# matching rows to list of values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 23 column dataframe where one of the columns called column_lei contain the LEIs of various companies, I also have a list called lei_codes which contains loads of specific LEIs which i need to find in the dataframe.

How could i run the list through each row in the lei column in the dataframe and if there is a match within any of the rows in that column to any of the values in the list for that entire row in the dataframe to be picked out and placed into a new dataframe. So at the end i have a new dataframe which contains all 23 columns of records where there was a match on the LEI column against the list.

Comment: Please share sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve it.

Comment: @Mayank Porwal   the main dateframe is : 'df = pd.read_excel(r"filepath", header = 0)' . I then imported the CSV which contains the LEIs using pd.read_csv and assigned it to data then I used 'lei_codes = list(data['lei codes'])' . I haven't tried to solve it yet.

Comment: _I haven't tried to solve it yet._ ??? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `isin()` on the column "column_lei"

Here an example with 3 columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.repeat("a", 5),
                   "column_lei": [1,2,3,4,5],
                   "b": np.repeat("b", 5)})
lei_codes = [1,3,5]
df_new = df[df.column_lei.isin(lei_codes)]
df_new
```